# Is it possible in C++ to access a variable based on its name (introspection)

Tags: c++, introspection

I was wondering if this is possible to do in C++. I have a function that takes user input for x and y bounds and I need to verify it, and it would be easier to do with one function. Is this possible in C++? Here's some pseudocode.

```
void bounds(char i){
  // if i is 'x' 
  std::cin >> [i]Lower    // store to xLower
  // verify
}
// then do
bounds('x');
bounds('y');
```

Comment: This is far from valid c++ code.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It's pseudocode. Sorry I'm new to C++.

Comment: @dustytrash I'm trying to set cin to input to xLower if the function has input character 'x' and input to yLower if it is input 'y'.

Comment: You can make a map of names to member pointers or to setter functions (depending on the case).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux but then he'd have to exhaustively list all cases. Some language offer introspection where you can just find your own members' name and access them this way

Comment: The normal way to do this is to use std::map - have a look at https://onlinegdb.com/B1zDaH_FX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, C++ code cannot do anything which depends on the variables name. e.g. If your variable is named x or y, it won't affect the code's behaviour.

Comment: Python, to some level, with dir(obj), getattr() and setattr()